# Preventation from starting a thread twice

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

Imagine you have a little calculation method, which is startet by a thread:

```
boost::mutex mMutex;

void MyClass::DoSomething {
  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> tLock(mMutex);
  if(tLock.owns_lock() {
    // do some stuff...
  }
}
```

And you want to start this in a thread, raised from different member functions. They can be called simultanous, but you can't know when:

```
void MyClass::Process {
  boost::thread t1(&MyClass::DoSomething, this);
  // go on ...
}

void MyClass::Foo {
  boost::thread t2(&MyClass::DoSomething, this);
  // and something more ...
}
```

How to prevent `t2` from beeing executed at all, if `t1` is running? My `unique_lock` seems to fail.

Comment: @Kerrek For `t2` a lock can also be acquired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a variable and before you start the `t1` thread, increase that variable in atomic way. When it finished, decrease that variable to null in atomic way. In `Foo` you should just check if this variable is null, or not.

[Check this example.](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/atomic/usage_examples.html)

Comment: This might be a solution, but i tried to figure out a way without incrementing, decreasing and checking. Because sometimes one simply can forget to do this :)

Comment: @Benjamin: it is more effective than mutex, what also should be locked and unlocked.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Naszta's idea, here's a possible approach using atomic bools and atomic swaps:

```
std::atomic<bool> thread_in_use(False);

void DoSomething()
{
  if (thread_in_use.exchange(true))
    return;

  // ...

  thread_in_use = false;
}
```